# When creating a WCF service, I get error: doesn't implement interface member

Tags: wcf

Error 1

> 'UserWcfService.userService' does not implement interface member
>   'UserWcfService.IuserService.Getuserdetails()'.
>   'UserWcfService.userService.Getuserdetails()' cannot implement an
>   interface member because it is not
>   public.   C:\Users\ravi\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\wcfservices\UserWcfService\UserWcfService\userService.svc.cs    16  18  UserWcfService

`userservice.svc.cs` code:

```
namespace UserWcfService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "userService" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select userService.svc or userService.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class userService : IuserService
    {
        public string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ToString();
        List<usertype> Getuserdetails()
    {
        List<usertype> userdetails=new List<usertype>();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);

        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spgetdata", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    usertype objinfo = new usertype();
                    objinfo.name = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["name"]);
                    objinfo.gender = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["gender"]);
                    objinfo.dateofbirth = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["dateofbirth"]);
                    objinfo.address = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["address"]);
                    objinfo.contactno = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["contactno"]);
                    objinfo.mailid = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["mailid"]);
                    userdetails.Add(objinfo);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return userdetails;
    }

    public string newuser(usertype user)
    {
            string strmessage; 
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spinsert", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_Name", user.name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_Gender", user.gender);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lC_Users_DOB", user.dateofbirth);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_Address", user.address);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_ContactNo", user.contactno);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_MailID", user.mailid);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_RegisteredDate", userinfo.date);
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if(result==1)
                {
                    strmessage = user.name + "details inserted succesfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    strmessage = user.name + "Details not inserted";
                }
                conn.Close();
            }

            return strmessage;
       }
    }
}
```

and `IUserService` code:

```
namespace UserWcfService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IuserService" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IuserService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<usertype> Getuserdetails();

        [OperationContract]
        string newuser(usertype user);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class usertype
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string gender { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime dateofbirth { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string address { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int contactno { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string mailid { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: mark your interface member public. They should always public

Answer (score 0):

All interface methods are by default public therefore your class which dervies interface needs to be public as well.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to see what you are doing wrong here is to right click on the IuserService in

```
public class userService : IuserService
```

go to implement interface -> implement interface explicitly

this will create the stub methods that are implementing your interface. you can either drop your code into those or you could adjust the methods that you have appropriately

Here is an example which built I derived using the method I described above

```
public class userService : IuserService
{
    public string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ToString();

    List<usertype> IuserService.Getuserdetails()
    {
        List<usertype> userdetails = new List<usertype>();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);

        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spgetdata", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    usertype objinfo = new usertype();
                    objinfo.name = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["name"]);
                    objinfo.gender = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["gender"]);
                    objinfo.dateofbirth = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["dateofbirth"]);
                    objinfo.address = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["address"]);
                    objinfo.contactno = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["contactno"]);
                    objinfo.mailid = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["mailid"]);
                    userdetails.Add(objinfo);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return userdetails;
    }

    public string newuser(usertype user)
    {
        string strmessage;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spinsert", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_Name", user.name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_Gender", user.gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lC_Users_DOB", user.dateofbirth);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_Address", user.address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_ContactNo", user.contactno);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_MailID", user.mailid);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_Users_RegisteredDate", userinfo.date);
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (result == 1)
            {
                strmessage = user.name + "details inserted succesfully";
            }
            else
            {
                strmessage = user.name + "Details not inserted";
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        return strmessage;
    }
```